# does AWS Lambda@Edge shares all available runtime(s) with Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda-edge

this question answered some differences between Lambda@Edge and Lambda
[What is the difference between AWS lambda and AWS Lambda@EDGE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745107/what-is-the-difference-between-aws-lambda-and-aws-lambdaedge)

but one more question is does Lambda@Edge and Lambda share all available runtime(s) ? Or can Lambda@Edge use all available Lambda runtime?

when this `nodejs14.x` was announced available in AWS Lambda, I want to find out does Lambda@Edge also have `nodejs14.x` ?
so far the latest I can search out is on Mar 2, 2020 they announced `nodejs12.x` for Lambda@Edge

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-14-x-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/ (on 03 FEB 2021)
- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/03/lambda-at-edge-node12-python38/ (Posted On: Mar 2, 2020)

Updated almost 3 months later:

- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/lambda-edge-support-node14/ (Posted On: Apr 29, 2021)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this I would say the answer to your question is "no": https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-node-js-12/

It seems Lambda support for Node.js 12 was added Nov. 18, 2019, but wasn't added to Lambda@Edge until Mar. 2, 2020... 3.5 months later.  If that same gap holds, then I wouldn't expect to see support for Node.js 14 land in Lambda@Edge until perhaps mid-May 2021.

Comment: Good prediction, looks like AWS actually added support for Node 14 at the end of April: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/lambda-edge-support-node14/

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, AWS lists the available runtimes in their docs, but in separate pages.

**As of Oct-2022**

| Runtime | [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) | [Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-restrictions.html#lambda-at-edge-function-restrictions) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Node.js 16 | ✔ | ✔ |
| Node.js 14 | ✔ | ✔ |
| Node.js 12 | `**` | ✔ |
| Node.js 10 | `*` | ✖ |
| Node.js 8 | `*` | ✖ |
| Node.js 6 | `*` | ✖ |

`**`*This version of Node.js has reached end of life, and it will soon be deprecated by AWS Lambda. Starting on November 14, 2022 you can't create new functions with this version of Node.js. Starting on December 14, 2022 you can't create or update functions with this version. (see Lambda docs for more information)*

`*`*This version of Node.js has reached end of life and is fully deprecated by AWS Lambda. You can't create or update functions with this version of Node.js. (see Lambda@Edge docs for more information)*